# Imports in Android Studio/IntelliJ13 not working, gradle command line running just fine

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I´m trying to get a gradle project running on my Mac, command line building works just fine. When I open the Project, all Android classes seem not to be found.

As a reference I also tried with this open source project (https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid) of a friend of mine. Same problem there.

[image: sample screenshot - my project]

[image: BarcodeHelper from PassAndroid]

I´ve tried with the sample code (BasicMediaRouter), provided with the SDK, and I only had to change the android plugin version that it was referencing, so everything seemed normal.

Building and running also works, it´s just Android Studio that is broken.

I have the same problems with IntelliJ CE13.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you running? If it's older than 0.5.2 or so, please upgrade. Current is 0.5.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up helping is using the import Project function on the build.gradle file.

File -> Open on the build.gradle file led to the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you click 'sync project with gradle files'? (you can find it using cmd+shift+a and write it)
What happens if you position cursor on the red word (for example Bitmap) and click Alt+Enter?

It looks like you did not set up Android SDK path. You can set in up in FIle->Project Structure->SDK Path (or similar depending on what version of Android Studio you have)

Comment: Sync did not help. The SDK path is set correctly. I´ll see if a reset of all AppCode will help.

Comment: What happens if you position cursor on the red word (for example Bitmap) and click Alt+Enter?